# Conflicting fatal error yylval

Tags: makefile, bison

When I use Makefile and link and compiler all source code, there is a fatal error that comes from cminus.y (bison/yacc) concerning **yylval**

How can I clear this error? Please help me

Here is the image of ERROR page

[image]

Comment: Sounds like you have multiple incompatible definitions of `yylval` or `YYSTYPE` -- hard to say without seeing you code...

Comment: There is no need to use images to insert a few lines from your console into a question. Just copy and paste the text into your question. And your image does not indicate how it is that compiling `parse.c` produces an error message referencing the file `cmimus.tab.c`; that suggests that you are `#include`ing one C file inside another one, which is not recommended. The error with `yylval` will have to do with the declarations in `parse.c`; as @chris says it is impossible to say more without seeing how `yylval` is declared, both in `parse.c` and in `cminus.y`